# python trio interrogate state of child_tasks

Tags: python-3.x, python-trio

with access to a `trio.Nursery` instance `nursery`, how may I print state of all `nursery.child_tasks`, specifically which have not yet exited?

I'm not understanding, reading docs & the `trio` `NurseryManager` code:

- how "nested child" tasks might be relevant. I see [direct] children removed when a task completes with `_child_finished()`, but am not understanding use of `_nested_child_finished()`.
- the window of time between one task failing (`raise`ing), and all tasks completing.  Being cooperative, I would expect to be able to find "active" tasks, in the window ~soon after one failure, with *both* states

  - "failed, exception captured"
  - and "running, has not handled `Canceled` yet"

Comment: what kind of state are you looking for? `child_tasks` only includes tasks that have not exited.

Comment: @NathanielJ.Smith - I can't disprove this looking in the debugger ... seems correct; but I was hoping to find it in docs.  Looking at the code it does appear to be the case (`def _child_finished` removes completed tasks), *however* looking through the code I see `_nested_child_finished` ... and it's not easy to ascertain enough of it's use to understand ....  so yes, specifically all tasks that have not completed (I think that would imply under a specific `nursery`)

Comment: edited (added to) question to elaborate ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Nested child" is our internal name for "the block of code that's actually part of the parent task, that you typed inside the `async with open_nursery():`. This code runs a bit differently than a real child task, but it has similar semantics (the nursery won't exit until it exits, if it raises an exception it cancels the real child tasks and vice-versa, etc.), so that's why we call it that.

You're correct that there's a window of time between one task `raise`ing and other tasks completing. When a task `raise`s then the other tasks get cancelled, but this means injecting `trio.Cancelled` exceptions, waiting for those exceptions to unwind, etc., so it might take some time. (You can tell check whether the nursery has been cancelled with `nursery.cancel_scope.cancel_called`.)

During this period, `nursery.child_tasks` will have only the tasks that are still running (i.e., still processing their cancellation). Currently Trio doesn't keep track of "failed tasks" – the nursery keeps a list of the exception objects themselves, so it can re-raise them, but it doesn't track which tasks those came from or anything, and there's currently no API to introspect the list of pending exceptions.

Zooming out: Trio's general philosophy is that when thinking about code organization, functions are more useful than tasks. So it really de-emphasizes tasks: outside of debugging/introspection/low-level-plumbing, you never encounter a "task object" or give a task a name. (See also [Go's take on this](https://go.dev/doc/faq#no_goroutine_id).) Depending on what you're doing, you might find it helpful to step back and think if there's a better way to keep track of what operations you're doing and how they're progressing.